# Android project does not run when target sdk is changed

Tags: android, eclipse

Currently project target sdk is google api level 14 and it runs well. If I changed target sdk to google api level 16 in android manifest file and run the project then it shows message `unfortunately, app has stopped`. Again if I change it back to level 14 then it runs.
Can anyone tell me the what can be the reason?

**EDIT :** logcat details

```
05-24 10:57:09.709: E/Trace(981): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.sentry.android.hmi.SentryApp: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{41321b58 981:com.sentry.android/u0a48} (pid=981, uid=10048) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4154) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{41321b58 981:com.sentry.android/u0a48} (pid=981, uid=10048) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2354) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4219) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:1703) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1099) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:354) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at com.sentry.android.hmi.SentryApp.onCreate(SentryApp.java:116) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151) 
05-24 10:57:11.108: E/AndroidRuntime(981): ... 10 more
```

Comment: What your logcat says exactly?

Comment: @PareshMayani I don't really understand what is written in logcat. I reopend eclipse so now old logcat details are not available.

Comment: On Which device you are running ? Have you checked the supported api level for that device... Instead of Google API 16 instead try default API 16.. May be that should work..

Comment: @Amit I run it on emulator. AVD version is set to google api level 17. this project use google apis and hence I have to use google api level.

Comment: Apart from changing in manifiest file try changing the project properties... right click on Project --> Properties --> Android --> check the API level there... Actually I think the .project file contains some other version...

Comment: @Amit in Project->Properties it is already google api level 16. Strange thing is that when manifest target is level 14 and I am able to run project that time also this Project->Properties is set to api level 16.

Comment: @Amit project.properties file has `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:16`.

Comment: look in the logcat. You should see a stack trace that indicates why your app crashed. Anything else is just pure speculation.

Comment: paste the logcat here...

Comment: @Amit Currently my eclipse is having another problem. As soon as it starts working I'll post logcat details.

Comment: You can always use logcat on the console. Just use `adb -e logcat` and paste the stacktrace here. No need to wait for eclipse.

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer where do I have to run this command? On terminal it says command not found.

Comment: Either you change the value of your PATH variable to point to the sdk/platform-tools directory or you prepend the path to the command.

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer added logcat details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30527/discussion-between-akash-patel-and-wolfram-rittmeyer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
```

If you are just reading this log, change the line to:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Put this line above of your `<application>` tag. Or, if you have other permission entries as well, where those others are.

Those permissions were added with the API-Level 16. See for example the [documentation to the value READ_CALL_LOG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CALL_LOG).